# can not see the result well ordered

Tags: android

I use a for loop which contains a function that shows 4  paragraphs. Running the application I see the paragraphs from No.4 to No.1 whereas it should be vice-versa.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
                paragraph(listArray[i]);
                next(listArray[i]);
            };
```

Comment: You need more info.

Comment: I have 4 different paragraph which I need to load them by running my application, in a special order that an array gave to me. The "paragraph " function contains paragraphs and action that I need to do on them. and "next" is a function containing Onclick event for next buttons. I have 4 different next button for each paragraph and by clicking it, the application should show the next paragraph and show a message. Even though I can see only the last message 4 times!, (without clicking the next button).

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the indices in the reverse order that you need then you could try looping backwards like this:

```
for (int i=3; i>-1; i--) {
    paragraph(listArray[i]);
    next(listArray[i]);
};
```

Notice that the index will start with `[3]` and go down to the first spot, `[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for answering I also checked this before but doesn't work. It is funny when I run it in debug mode it works well, but when I run it as the application, the problem appears.

Comment: If you post more of your code I might be able to help you further